# What to use instead of AlwaysOnHotwordDetector in android which is now deprecated?

Tags: android, voice-recognition, google-assistant, google-voice-actions, hotword

I am working on developing an offline google assistant alternative using DeepSpeech voice recognition model. Am using Voice-Interaction Service and sessions for same. however, I also want that  "hey-Google" like feature. I have been seeing many guides and they point to AlwaysOnHotwordDetector. However in the latest android api that is deprecated.... what to do?